# Problema com o teclado de trás para frente no Flutter

Tags: flutter

Meu flutter está atualizado, logo pensei que fosse o emulador mas não é, testei no dispositivo físico e o erro continua, toda vez que eu digito algo no textfield sai ao contrário, por exemplo, se eu digito "maisa" no aplicativo aparece "asiam". Eu até criei um projeto vazio mas o problema continua.  A versão do meu flutter é a 3.7.8 e a do dart é 2.19.5. Segue meu código:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MainApp({super.key});
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  bool hasNull = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 70,
            child: TextField(
              textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
              controller: textEditingController,
              onChanged: (value) => textEditingController.text = value,
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                errorText: hasNull ? 'Este campo não pode ficar vazio!' : null,
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 20,
                  horizontal: 20,
                ),
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    width: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
                focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    width: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    width: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    width: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
                labelText: 'Prontuário',
                labelStyle:
                    TextStyle(color: hasNull ? Colors.red : Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete esta linha:

```dart
onChanged: (value) => textEditingController.text = value,
```

e seu problema deve ser resolvido.

Acredito que ela também não faça muito sentido pois a propriedade `text` do `TextEditingController` já é atualizada automaticamente quando ele está vinculado a um `TextField`. Eles estão vinculados com a seguinte linha:

```dart
 controller: textEditingController,
```

O problema acontecia porque sempre que o texto do `Textfield` é modificado por código (é o que faz a linha que sugeri deletar), a inserção de texto volta para o começo. Então a cada caractere digitado, a inserção voltava ao começo e o seguinte era digitado ao começo da frase. Assim dava a impressão que estava sendo escrito ao contrário.